# How to insert Null values Oracle Types

Tags: java, oracle

This is my code to call procedure from java.

```
String DocumentSQL = "{call PKG_CREATE.PROC_CREATE_Claim(?,?)}";
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(insertDocumentSQL);
callableStatement.setString(1,"Test");
callableStatement.setArray(2,claimArray);
```

Here I have used Oracle type Array. When claimArray has values its working fine. Sometimes it will be Null. So that I added like this

```
if(claimArray!=null){
   callableStatement.setArray(2,claimArray);
}
else {                         
   callableStatement.setArray(2,null);
   or 
   callableStatement.setNull(2, OracleTypes.NULL);
}
```

It shows Error. How I can set Null Array?

Comment: Show the error message please

Comment: if(claimArray!=null){
    
    callableStatement.setArray(2,claimArray);
    } else
    
     callableStatement.setArray(2,null);

How exactly do you think this differs from

    callableStatement.setArray(2,claimArray);

Writing more code is not always better.
"It shows Error", can you be more specific? check the table design. If it is declared as not nullable, no, you can't add null, otherwise, yes.

Comment: Did you try `callableStatement.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to se a null array you should create a void array like this:

```
  callableStatement.setArray(2,new typeArray[size]);
```

For example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[4];
    for (String i : arr) {

        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
 null
 null
 null
 null
```

Comment: what you mean typeArray[size]. Can you post some example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 3 parameter setNull() function for the null case:

> void setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType, String sql_type_name)
>
> takes a SQL type name in addition to a parameter index and a SQL type
>   code. You use this method only when the SQL type code is REF, ARRAY,
>   or STRUCT.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/oraext3.htm